# "Die Emailadresse dürfte als „nomen est omen“ gewählt worden sein?"

Tags: idiom, vocabulary

Nachdem ich der Wiener Grenzpolizei eine Frage stellte, wurde ich aufs "Fachgebiet Polizei & Katastrophenschutz" der Bezirkshauptmannschaft Bruck a.d. Leitha hingewiesen.

Von diesem bekam ich vor der tatsächlichen Antwort folgende Nachricht separat:

> Wie von Ihnen gewünscht, geben wir Ihnen hiermit Bescheid, dass wir Ihre Nachricht sorgfältig durchgelesen haben.
>
> Die Emailadresse dürfte als „nomen est omen“ gewählt worden sein?

Was wollte man mir eigentlich damit sagen? Ich habe "nomen est omen" auf Google aufgesucht, doch in diesem Zusammenhang sagt es mir trotzdem wenig.

**Zur Klarstellung**: meine E-mailadresse enthält das Wort "Joker". Die Frage an die Wiener Grenzpolizei war u.a. ob ich als schwedischer Staatsangehöriger (angesichts COVID-19 Beschränkungen) bei einer Zwischenlandung auf Schwechat ins Land einreisen darf, um im Flughafenhotel zu übernachten. Die Polizei hat mich auf die andere Behörde hingeweisen, ich habe den Nachrichtenverlauf an diese weitergeleitet und um eine sorgfältige Überprüfung und Bescheid gebeten. Natürlich habe ich mich konsequent formell und anständig ausgedrückt.

Comment: "Emailadresse" ist natürlich ein Rechtschreibfehler, sofern nicht die Wohnanschrift für einen glasharten, gegen Korrosion und Temperaturschwankungen beständigen Schmelzüberzug, der als Schutz oder zur Verzierung auf metallische Oberflächen aufgetragen wird, gemeint ist.

Comment: Es wäre hilfreich, für das "Nomen est omen" den "relevanten Teil der E-Mail-Adresse in die Frage mit aufzunehmen. Meistens ist es etwas vor dem @, das danach ist die Domain und kann sehr viele betreffen, während das davor meinst selbst gewählt wurde. Auch trägt der Kontext der Anfrage (Kommentar an einer Antwort) zum Verständnis der Frage bei - also "warum frage ich mit welcher Adresse bei wem an?". (=der gegebene Kontext ist ein guter Start, nur für die Frage zu wenig)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58904/die-emailadresse-d%c3%bcrfte-als-nomen-est-omen-gew%c3%a4hlt-worden-sein#comment144268_58905

Comment: @Crazydre: hm, das ist der Grund warum ich so lange drum herum schrieb: Kommentare können verschwinden, eine Frage muss aus dem Fragentext allein verständlich sein. Ohne Kommentare bei irgendeiner Antwort - auch nicht bei ihr selbst -> https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment (dass sich manche Info erst später als relevant herausstellt ist kein Hinderungsgrund es später aufzunehmen)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Hab' die Frage aktualisiert :)

Answer (score 4):

`Nomen est Omen` heißt, dass der Name auf den Inhalt oder den Charakter hinweist. Wenn die Behörde Bescheid gibt, dass sie die Nachricht sorgfältig gelesen hat, heißt das nichts anderes, als dass die Nachricht keinen besonderen Wert hat. Dei Behörde ergreift keine Maßnahme, aus der Nachricht folgt nichts. Wenn die E-Mail-Adresse jetzt noch `Blödian2000` at yahoo dot com lautet, passt alles zusammen.

Answer (score 3):

Diese Frage zu 100% richtig zu beantworten ist wahrscheinlich selbst bei komplett vorliegenden E-Mail-Verkehr ein Ding der Unmöglichkeit, da man in den Absender nicht hineinsehen kann und so nur Mutmassungen anstellen kann.

Die Anhaltspunkte sind hier jedoch:

- das bereitgestellten Zitat
- eine E-Mailadresse die das Wort "Joker" enthält

Anhand der Aussage des Absenders, dass dieser bestätigt, deine Nachricht "wie gewünscht" sorgfältig durchgelesen zu haben, ist davon auszugehen, dass du genau das gefordert hast. Also selbst etwas geschrieben hast wie:

> Bitte lesen sie meine Nachricht sorgfältig durch.

Ausgehend von einem "korrekt" arbeitendem Mitglied der Wiener Grenzpolizei wird dieser von sich selbst (höchstwahrscheinlich) ausgehen jede E-Mail/Nachricht von sich aus sorgfältig zu lesen. Die explizite Aufforderung, dies zu machen, von ihm also als (schlechter) Scherz aufgefasst werden könnte. Bzw. er könnte denken, dass ihm durch diese Aufforderung sogar schludriges Arbeiten vorgeworfen würde.

Von dieser Interpretation ausgehend, wäre eine E-Mailadresse die das Wort "Joker" enthält, die eines "Witzbolds". Daher die Verwendung "[Nomen est Omen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen_est_omen)".

> Nomen est omen ist eine lateinische Redensart und bedeutet „der Name ist ein Zeichen“. Sie wird meist gebraucht, um auszudrücken, dass der Name eine Person oder Sache treffend kennzeichnet, oft auch übertreibend oder ironisch gebrochen. Zum besseren Verständnis kann man es frei mit „Der Name ist Programm“ übersetzen.

Aber wie gesagt: reinste Spekulation.

Comment: Du hast vermutlich Recht! Ich habe in der Tat folgendes an die zweite Behörde geschrieben: "Könnten Sie bitte meine untenstehende Nachricht an die Grenzpolizei sorgfältig durchlesen und mir Bescheid geben?". Wenn ich lange Nachrichten mit mehreren Fragen sende, kommt es nämlich öfters vor, dass die Anfrage nur zum Teil beantwortet wird, vll. weil die Länge der Nachricht überfordernd ist. Ist menschlich, also habe ich eben das zitierte mitgenommen. Meiner Meinung nach äusserst unprofessionell seitens des Beamten, mich deswegen in formeller Korrespondenz zu schimpfen

Comment: Über die Intention des Beamten kann man auch nur spekulieren. Vielleicht wollte er dir einen Mitgeben. Vielleicht wollte er auch nur selbst witzig sein. Man weiß es nicht.